# Auth0 logout issue in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, auth0

Currently in my Xamairn.Android I have 2 activities Mainactivity and SignoutActivity.
In my Mainactivity I have a button where when user clicks the button it goes to SignoutActivity.

Here I have implemented the signout codes of Auth0.

Here are the codes-
In MainAcitivity-

```
this.Signout.Click += delegate
    {
         using (var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SignOutActivity)))
            {
                this.StartActivity(intent);
            }
    };
```

SignOutAcitivity-

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.LogoutAsync();
    Finish();

}
public async Task<BrowserResult> LogoutAsync()
{
    var clientOptions = new Auth0.OidcClient.Auth0ClientOptions
    {
        Domain ="",
        ClientId = "",
        Scope = "openid email offline_access",
        Browser = new PlatformWebView()
    };
    var logoutUrl = "Signout URl";
    string redirectUri = "I have proper callback uri";

    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("client_id", "random1234");
    dictionary.Add("returnTo", clientOptions.RedirectUri);

    string endSessionUrl = new RequestUrl(logoutUrl).Create(dictionary);

    var logoutRequest = new LogoutRequest();
    BrowserResult browserResult = null;

    browserResult = await clientOptions.Browser.InvokeAsync(new BrowserOptions(endSessionUrl, redirectUri)
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)logoutRequest.BrowserTimeout),
        DisplayMode = logoutRequest.BrowserDisplayMode
    });

    return browserResult;
}
```

Platformview-

```
class PlatformWebView : IBrowser
{
public Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.StartUrl))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Missing StartUrl", nameof(options));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.EndUrl))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Missing EndUrl", nameof(options));
    }
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BrowserResult>();

    void Callback(string response)
    {
        ActivityMediator.Instance.ActivityMessageReceived -= Callback;

        // set result
        if (response == "UserCancel")
        {
            tcs.SetResult(new BrowserResult { ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel });
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetResult(new BrowserResult
            {
                Response = response,
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success
            });
        }
    }
    ActivityMediator.Instance.ActivityMessageReceived += Callback;
    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(options.StartUrl);
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory)
        .AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    return tcs.Task;
}
}
}
```

Problem is browser never returns to app,Also I have put a debugger at return browserResult,this debugger also does not hit.Please help me.

Comment: According to your description and code, I can not run your project at my side, can you upload your project in github and I will upload your project and try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I am not sure how u r running the project...Its simple...i have 2 activities..in first activity i have a logout button(have provided the codes),after clicking it it will go to signoutactivity class.Regarding platformview and activitymediator class i have taken those directly from auth0 documentation https://github.com/auth0/auth0-oidc-client-net

Comment: Are you able to get this